# How can I know whether my Windows SMTP server gets connected to its recipient server?

Tags: windows, smtp

I have a Winodws SMTP virtual server on Windows 2012R2. It sent many emails to someone@vt.edu. However, recipients never get sent emails.

I contacted the technical support at Virginia Tech and they asked me to send test emails to certain vt.edu addresses and they said they were unable to find any trace of the sent emails. How could this happen? Where should I look to fix the problem?

Please note this same server is able to successfully send emails to many other recipients such as Gmail addresses and other business email addresses.

Thanks so much for any help and input!

Comment: anybody voting to close your question should give a reason

Comment: You can use wireshark and see the communication going as input to the SMTP server and  coming as output from it You might have more luck seeing things in wireshark if you don't make the client 127.0.0.1. So  if the SMTP server is on CompX, connect to it from CompA. Then from CompX you should see the traffic coming in and out.

Comment: Can you make a testing delivery from this box with `telnet inbound.smtp.vt.edu. 25`?

Comment: No. I dont have any account at VT's server. This problem got fixed today. The problem is that my network adapter have both ipv6 and ipv4 checked.     After uncheck ipv6, the emails can be delivered without any problem. Thanks for asking!!!